# Azure Elastic Pool eDTU and Storage per DB / Pool?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool, azure-cost-calculation

This is regarding azure SQL database pricing, in elastic pool, standard 50 eDTU performance level, they have mentioned that there are 50 eDTU and 50 GB per pool and 100 DBs, i want to confirm whether the mentioned resources is per pool or per database.

for example, if i deploy 10 databases, then 50GB and 50 eDTU will be shared among the databases or is it for individual databases ?

in case, resources are for individual databases, then the price,which is now $110.26 per month, does it change based on the number of databases or is it estimated monthly cost regardless of the database count. does database count affect the monthly pricing ?

in case, resources are for entire pool, if i am going deploy 100 databases, then single database can not be more than 500 MB ? am i right ? does not it seems odd ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:
The price, which is now $110.26 per month, does it change based on the number of databases or is it estimated monthly cost regardless of the database count. does database count affect the monthly pricing?

**Yes it will impact on the pricing when resources are from individual.**

Questions 2:
In case, resources are for entire pool, if i am going deploy 100 databases, then single database cannot be more than 500 MB? am I right? does not it seems odd??

**single database resources limits are generally as same as which are in elastic pools based on DTUs and the service tier.  But only difference is
if database in an elastic pool DTU utilization is 100%, it will utilize eDTU utilization from pool. That means elastic pool will support maximum number of DTU per database.**

Here is the same reference of elastic pool and normal database implementations.

Created a multiple database under elastic pool and one normal database excluded from elastic pools.
[image]

[image]

Per database configurations we can set entire pool size of limited size also, depends on utilization of DTUs.
**NOTE: If DTU's utilization of databases is very low, we can decrease the pool's size. It will reduce our costs over time.**

[image]
Hope it's useful.

Comment: Noted with Thanks